# Dependency problem while processing CUPS

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I tried to update ubuntu but got a prob tried

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  icedtea-7-jre-cacao screen-resolution-extra
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cups
Suggested packages:
  cups-pdf
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cups
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 514 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,278 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,305 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups:
 cups-filters (1.0.18-0ubuntu0.1) breaks cups (<< 1.5.0-16) and is installed.
  Version of cups to be configured is 1.5.0-8ubuntu6.
dpkg: error processing cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 cups
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

what do i do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prevent `cups` package from automatic upgrade,

```
sudo apt-mark hold cups
```

Now fix the dependencies,

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: thanxx its okk now